# Makefile with Fortran - src and bin directories

Tags: makefile, fortran

I'm having some trouble understanding how to design my makefile to build my project the way I want to. Specifically, I can't figure out how to keep all source files in a `src` directory, while putting all binaries in a `bin` directory except the linked executable, which goes in the project root.

This is my makefile:

```
# Compiler options
FC          :=  mpif90
FFLAGS      :=  -O3 -g -Wall -Warray-bounds -ffixed-line-length-none -fbounds-check 
VPATH       :=  src
BINDIR      :=  bin

# Define file extensions
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .f .o .mod 

# All modules
OBJS        :=  $(BINDIR)/ratecoeffs.o $(BINDIR)/interpolation.o $(BINDIR)/io.o $(BINDIR)/eedf.o $(BINDIR)/single_particle.o $(BINDIR)/physics.o $(BINDIR)/random.o $(BINDIR)/mpi.o $(BINDIR)/precision.o $(BINDIR)/populations.o 

# Build rules
all: runner | $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(VPATH)/%.f | $(BINDIR)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

runner: $(OBJS)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BINDIR)
```

Running `make` builds everything allright - it finds all source files in `src` and puts all `.o` files in `bin` - but the module files (`.mod`) that are generated by the compiler are put in the project root instead of in the `bin` directory. I realize I could just specify a rule to place them there, but [that messes with the build order, and will sometimes break the build](http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/mwest/f90_mod_deps/).

What is the "correct" way to get this behavior?

*And yes, I've looked at autotools and automake, but I've never used them before and they seem to be overkill for this project. As I couldn't find any good tutorials on how they work (no, I didn't like [the tutorial on gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/#introduction)) I'd prefer if I could avoid having to learn this tool just to get this work...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your underlying Fortran compiler is gfortran, use the -J command line option.

```
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -J$(BINDIR)
```

With an eye to the future, you may be better off creating a MODDIR or similar variable, that you use instead of BINDIR.  Object code (*.o) and mod files have different roles to play in later compilation and linking steps - in larger projects they are often kept separate.

Comment: The `-J` option seems to be just what I'm looking for! All the files end up where I want them =) However, the build fails, because `gfortran` doesn't know to look in `bin/` for the `.mod`s. How do I specify that they're there?

Comment: Also, regarding creating a `MODDIR` - I would if this project was larger, but it's only about 15 source files (and won't grow much more), so one directory is fine with me.

Comment: It's odd, though - the first file builds OK; it has no dependencies. The second depends on the first, but builds OK. The third depends on both the first and second, and fails because it cannot find a couple of variables defined in the second module - but the files are there, and the variable is defined (correctly specified in the source file, mentioned in the mod file, although I don't know the mod format so I can't say if something's wrong there...). [Here's the mod file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5673502/) - the symbols that can't be found are `rnk` and `nproc`.

Comment: The directory specified with -J is also added to the list of directories searched for .mod files.  Perhaps you have an old mod file being picked up in preference from a different location to the "real" mod file.

Comment: No, that's not it - the problem persists even if I remove all build output before I start. And actually, the exact error message is "Error: Symbol 'rnk' referenced at (1) not found in module 'mpi'", so I guess the module is found, but not the variable in the module.

Comment: The module MPI being picked up will be the one that is part of MPI (as in the Message-Parsing Interface standard, which presumably you are using given the name of the compiler driver), and not your module.

Comment: Good catch - renaming the module fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably more in the sense of the make system to change into the obj-directory and do the compilation from there. Via the `VPATH` option you can let make to find your source files automatically. You could easily call your makefile recursively from the right directory. Below you find a trivial example which would be straightforward to adapt to your case. Please note, that it only works with GNU make.

```
ifeq (1,$(RECURSED))
VPATH = $(SRCDIR)
########################################################################
# Project specific makefile
########################################################################
FC = gfortran
FCOPTS = 
LN = $(FC)
LNOPTS = 

OBJS = accuracy.o eqsolver.o io.o linsolve.o

linsolve: $(OBJS)
    $(LN) $(LNOPTS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCOPTS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean realclean
clean:
    rm -f *.mod *.o
realclean: clean
    rm -f linsolve


accuracy.o:
eqsolver.o: accuracy.o
io.o: accuracy.o
linsolve.o: accuracy.o eqsolver.o io.o

else
########################################################################
# Recusive invokation
########################################################################
BUILDDIR = _build
LOCALGOALS = $(BUILDDIR) distclean
RECURSIVEGOALS = $(filter-out $(LOCALGOALS), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
.PHONY: all $(RECURSIVE_GOALS) distclean
all $(RECURSIVEGOALS): $(BUILDDIR)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) -f $(CURDIR)/GNUmakefile SRCDIR=$(CURDIR) \
            RECURSED=1 $(RECURSIVEGOALS)
$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir $(BUILDDIR)
distclean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
endif
```

The principle is simple:

- In the first part you write your normal makefile, as if you would create the object files in the source directory. However, additionally you add the `VPATH` option to make sure the source files are found (as make will be in the directory `BUILDDIR` when this part of the makefile is processed).
- In the second part (which is executed first, when the variable `RECURSED` is not set yet), you change to the `BUILDIR` directory and invoke your makefile from there. You pass some helper variables (e.g. the current directory) and all make goals, apart of those, which must be executed from outside `BUILDDIR` (e.g. distclean and the one creating `BUILDDIR` itself). The rules for those goals you specify also in the second part.